# script to writer to sheet after checking other cells times out

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet that is 11000 rows X 50 columns.  I need to check the city and state on each row and set a field, call region, accordingly.  This takes forever and times out after completing only 25% of the way through the sheet. I am very new to App Scripts and Javascript.  There must be a better way to do this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Here's the script:

```
    function setRegion() {
      var region = "Not Found";
      var state;
      var city;

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Comp Server List');
      var lastRow =sheet.getLastRow(); 
      var startRow = 5;
      console.log("10");
      for (n = startRow; n < lastRow; n++){
        var state = sheet.getRange(n,8).getValue();
        var city = sheet.getRange(n,7).getValue();
        switch(state) {
          case "AZ":
          region = "Arizona";
          break;
          case "NV":
            if (city == "Papillion"){
              region = "Enterprise Data Center";
            } else {
              region = "Northern California";
            };
          break;
          case "CA":
            switch(city){
              case "Santa Maria":
              case "Rancho Cordova":
              case "Sacramento":
              case "Folsom":
              case "Carmichael":
              case "Grass Valley":
              case "Woodland":
              case "Shasta":
              case "Redding":
              case "Red Bluff":
              case "Santa Cruz":
              case "San Francisco":
              case "Redwood":
              case "San Francisco":
                region = "Northern California";
                break;
              case "Camarillo":
              case "Oxnard":
              case "Bakersfield":
              case "Merced":
              case "San Andreas":
              case "Stockton":
              case "Arroyo Grande":
              case "San Luis Obispo":
              case "Los Angeles":
              case "San Bernardino":
              case "Glendale":
              case "Northridge":
              case "San Bernardino":
              case "Long Beach":
              case "Redlands":
              case "Pasadena":
                region = "Northern California";
                break;
            }
            // code block
            break;
          case "NE":
            if (city == "Papillion"){
              region = "Enterprise Data Center";
            } else {
              region = "Texas";
            };
            break;
          case "IA":
          case "ND":
          case "MN":
            region = "Midwest";
          break;
          
          case "WA":
          case "OR":
            region = "Midwest";
          break;
          case "KY":
          case "OH":
          case "TN":
          case "GA":
          case "AR":
            region = "Southeast";
          break;
            
          case "TX":
          case "NM":
            if (city == "Richardson"){
              region = "Enterprise Data Center";
            } else {
              region = "Texas";
            };
            break;
          case "CO":
            region = "Enterprise Data Center";
            break;
          default:
            region = "Not Found";
            break;
          } 
          console.log("row = "+n,"state ="+ state, "city ="+ city, "region = "+ region);
          sheet.getRange(n,9).setValue(region);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking can be found in [the official best practices guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations):

> Scripts commonly need to read in data from a spreadsheet, perform calculations, and then write out the results of the data to a spreadsheet. Google Apps Script already has some built-in optimization, such as using look-ahead caching to retrieve what a script is likely to get and write caching to save what is likely to be set.
>
> You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command.

So use `getValues()` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)) once, compute the result, and then call `setValues(values)` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)) with everything.